# Uninstall meta package with related extensions

Tags: magento2, module, composer

I created 2 (but planning to create 999 :) ) extensions and a meta package for it.

The meta package extension contains only composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "sergei/module-main",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "type": "metapackage",
    "require": {
        "sergei/module-one": "1.0.0",
        "sergei/module-two": "1.0.0"      
    }
}
```

For installation I run `composer require sergei/module-main` and all of required modules

```
sergei/module-one (Sergei_One in registration.php)
sergei/module-two (Sergei_Two in registration.php)
```

were successfully installed.

Each of these modules has `Setup/Uninstall.php`

In `vendor` directory metapackage (suppose `sergei/module_main`) was't added and I cannot run bin/magento module:uninstall Sergei_Main

How can I  run `bin/magento module:uninstall` for meta package?

I run `bin/magento module:uninstall Sergei_One Sergei_Two` - it works, but this method is ugly for me:

`Sergei_One` and `Sergei_Two` (... planning to create 999+ extensions...)) were deleted, but link to the meta package extension 
remain in the `composer.json` file.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you will have at least one module that is a dependency to other modules.
I mean one that is required by every other module directly or indirectly.
You can create your own console command in this module that removes all the installed modules.
[Here is a nice tutorial](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/console-command-magento-2/) that shows you how to create a command.
Just create something that can be executed like `bin/magento sergei:uninstall` that collects all your modules and runs `bin/magento module:uninstall` with all the module names as parameters.